# NHibernate many-to-many

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

Ввязался в проект `asp.net mvc4, c#, MS sql,Nhibernate`. Маппинг посредством `XML`. Есть три таблицы `Recovery, Tools, RecoveryTools` (одной записи `Recovery` может соответствовать много из `Tools` и наоборот `many-to-many` посредством `RecoveryTools`). В  `RecoveryTools` всего два поля-это `RecoveryId`  и `ToolsId`. 1)Нужно отразить в Html разметке `Recovery` (обычным форычем) и щелкнув по любой `RecoveryItems` попасть на страничку завязанных на нее `Tools` (блин почему же они выбрали этот `NHibernate`--я не в силах его победить.).

ВОПРОС--как смаппить и какие классы завести в `Domain`. Очень надо, помогите, друзья.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В "домене" 2 класса:

```
class Recovery
{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Tools> Tools { get; set; }
}

class Tools
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recovery> Recoveries { get; set; }
}
```

Маппинг:

```
<class name="Recovery">
   <id name="Id" />
   <set name="Tools" table="RecoveryTools">
       <key column="RecoveryId" />
       <many-to-many column="ToolsId" />
   </set>
</class>

<class name="Tools">
   <id name="Id" />
   <set name="Recoveries" table="RecoveryTools">
       <key column="ToolsId" />
       <many-to-many column="RecoveryId" />
   </set>
</class>
```